# Is the Expression Transformation 's output port's size independent of the precision set for it?

Tags: expression, transformation, informatica-powercenter

In an expression transformation I am using an output port which is dependent on an input port(no logic just straight pass). The precision that I have set for the Input Port is 10 and that of Output Port is 1.

But the data from the Output Port is not getting truncated.

For eg. say I have the value "Ashish" that is Input into the expression Transform (port name i_Name, precision 10). The corresponding output port (port name o_Name, precision 1) still gives the value "Ashish".

According to me the value should get truncated to "A".

Although I know the solution to this issue:
- Use Substring function
- Use a variable port
But I was wondering why the original method does not trim the value.

It would be great if someone could help me figure out the reason to this issue.

Thanks